# Neural network classifier poker

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am currently trying to create a neural network to predict poker hands, I am quite new to machine learning and neural networks and might need some help!I found some tutorials on how to create a neural network and this is my try in trying to adapt this data set to it.The following code is making pycharm crash
here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pnd
# sigmoid function


def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv:
        return x * (1 - x)
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
# InputData
training_data = pnd.read_csv("train.csv")
print(training_data)
training_data = training_data.drop(['hand'], axis=1)
print(training_data)
X = np.array(training_data)

# output data
training_data = pnd.read_csv("train.csv")
print(training_data)
training_data = training_data.drop(['S1'], axis=1)
training_data = training_data.drop(['C1'], axis=1)
training_data = training_data.drop(['S2'], axis=1)
training_data = training_data.drop(['C2'], axis=1)
training_data = training_data.drop(['S3'], axis=1)
training_data = training_data.drop(['C3'], axis=1)
training_data = training_data.drop(['S4'], axis=1)
training_data = training_data.drop(['C4'], axis=1)
training_data = training_data.drop(['S5'], axis=1)
training_data = training_data.drop(['C5'], axis=1)
print(training_data)
Y = np.array(training_data).T
print(Y)
# input dataset
# seed random numbers to make calculation
# deterministic (just a good practice)
np.random.seed(1)
# initialize weights randomly with mean 0
syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((10, 25011)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((10, 1)) - 1

for j in range(10000):
    # Feed forward through layers 0, 1, and 2
    l0 = X
    l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0, syn0))
    l2 = nonlin(np.dot(l1, syn1))
    # how much did we miss the target value?
    l2_error = y - l2
    if (j % 10000) == 0:
        print("Error:" + str(np.mean(np.abs(l2_error))))
    # in what direction is the target value
    # were we really sure? if so, don't change too much.
    l2_delta = l2_error * nonlin(l2, deriv=True)
    # how much did each l1 value contribute to the l2 error (according to the weights)?
    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)
    # in what direction is the target l1?
    # were we really sure? if so, don't change too much.
    l1_delta = l1_error * nonlin(l1, deriv=True)
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)
```

The following is a snippet of my data set:
[Data set snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LDNe.jpg)

And the following is an explanation of the data set i am using:
Attribute Information:

```
1) S1 "Suit of card #1" 
Ordinal (1-4) representing {Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs} 

2) C1 "Rank of card #1" 
Numerical (1-13) representing (Ace, 2, 3, ... , Queen, King) 

3) S2 "Suit of card #2" 
Ordinal (1-4) representing {Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs} 

4) C2 "Rank of card #2" 
Numerical (1-13) representing (Ace, 2, 3, ... , Queen, King) 

5) S3 "Suit of card #3" 
Ordinal (1-4) representing {Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs} 

6) C3 "Rank of card #3" 
Numerical (1-13) representing (Ace, 2, 3, ... , Queen, King) 

7) S4 "Suit of card #4" 
Ordinal (1-4) representing {Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs} 

8) C4 "Rank of card #4" 
Numerical (1-13) representing (Ace, 2, 3, ... , Queen, King) 

9) S5 "Suit of card #5" 
Ordinal (1-4) representing {Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs} 

10) C5 "Rank of card 5" 
Numerical (1-13) representing (Ace, 2, 3, ... , Queen, King) 

11) CLASS "Poker Hand" 
Ordinal (0-9) 

0: Nothing in hand; not a recognized poker hand 
1: One pair; one pair of equal ranks within five cards 
2: Two pairs; two pairs of equal ranks within five cards 
3: Three of a kind; three equal ranks within five cards 
4: Straight; five cards, sequentially ranked with no gaps 
5: Flush; five cards with the same suit 
6: Full house; pair + different rank three of a kind 
7: Four of a kind; four equal ranks within five cards 
8: Straight flush; straight + flush 
9: Royal flush; {Ace, King, Queen, Jack, Ten} + flush
```

The variables being used:

```
Variable    Definition
X   Input dataset matrix where each row is a training example
y   Output dataset matrix where each row is a training example
l0  First Layer of the Network, specified by the input data
l1  Second Layer of the Network, otherwise known as the hidden layer
l2  Final Layer of the Network, which is our hypothesis, and should approximate the correct answer as we train.
syn0    First layer of weights, Synapse 0, connecting l0 to l1.
syn1    Second layer of weights, Synapse 1 connecting l1 to l2.
l2_error    This is the amount that the neural network "missed".
l2_delta    This is the error of the network scaled by the confidence. It's almost identical to the error except that very confident errors are muted.
l1_error    Weighting l2_delta by the weights in syn1, we can calculate the error in the middle/hidden layer.
l1_delta    This is the l1 error of the network scaled by the confidence. Again, it's almost identical to the l1_error except that confident errors are muted.
```

Comment: I am sure the program wont make the *computer* crash. In the worst case it will make the process crash. Also some information on what error (or any other message) you receive at the time of the crash would be helpful to pinpoint bug.

Comment: IMO you can cut down the explanation of how your neural net works. That is irrelevant to the crash.

Answer (score 0):

First you should definitely clarify whether this is crashing your computer or your process.

If it is your computer, check your RAM specs and how much is in use (top, htop, etc.) when you launch the NN.

Your syn0 matrix is 10x25011. That's 10 * 25011 * 8 / 1024 = 1953kB. If you're putting almost 2 gigs into a single variable in Python and running a bunch of Chrome tabs, a full shutdown is a real possibility.